# How to create an 'Action button' to reset the selection in ECharts2Shiny bar chart

Tags: r, shiny

I want to reset the selection to barchart. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ECharts2Shiny)

demo <- data.frame(c(5,0,0,1,20,25,14,1,53),
               c(1,1,1,2,12,22,5,1,25),
               c(6,0,0,3,26,38,19,2,65),
               c(0,0,0,0,5,3,0,0,6),
               c(0,1,1,0,1,6,0,0,7),
               c(6,0,1,3,32,47,19,2,78),
               c(2,0,0,1,8,13,10,1,33),
               c(0,0,0,0,0,9,2,0,4),
               c(1,0,0,1,6,4,6,0,23))
names(demo) <- c("M", "F", "O", "B", "C", "Re", "Vi", "Ac", "Co")
row.names(demo) <- c("Az","Bh", "Bi", "Ch", "Ha", "Ka", "N.G", "Ra", "Su") 

ui <- mainPanel(tabPanel(h5("Block wise"), loadEChartsLibrary(), 
tags$div(id="demo1", style="width:100%;height:500px;"), deliverChart(div_id= 
"demo1"),downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data")))
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
             renderBarChart(div_id = "demo1", grid_left = '1%', direction = 
"vertical", data = demo)})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

How to create a **Reset** button to deselect the selection of attributes?
Also I need help to download the data in excel csv format. Download data button pops up an window which ask to save the file but not allow us to select the "Save As Type" which is just below the "File Name" input bar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the plot can be done with `shinyjs` to execute the `js` code: `location.reload();`

The downloadButton has to have server component to save the data in the given file format.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ECharts2Shiny)
library(shinyjs)

demo <- data.frame(c(5,0,0,1,20,25,14,1,53),
                   c(1,1,1,2,12,22,5,1,25),
                   c(6,0,0,3,26,38,19,2,65),
                   c(0,0,0,0,5,3,0,0,6),
                   c(0,1,1,0,1,6,0,0,7),
                   c(6,0,1,3,32,47,19,2,78),
                   c(2,0,0,1,8,13,10,1,33),
                   c(0,0,0,0,0,9,2,0,4),
                   c(1,0,0,1,6,4,6,0,23))
names(demo) <- c("M", "F", "O", "B", "C", "Re", "Vi", "Ac", "Co")
row.names(demo) <- c("Az","Bh", "Bi", "Ch", "Ha", "Ka", "N.G", "Ra", "Su") 

ui <- mainPanel( shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tabPanel(h5("Block wise"), loadEChartsLibrary(), 
          actionButton("reset","reset plot"),
          tags$div(id="demo1", style="width:100%;height:500px;"), 
          deliverChart(div_id="demo1"),
          downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data")))
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    shinyjs::runjs("location.reload();")
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
  },
  content = function(con) {
    write.csv(demo, con)
  }
)

  renderBarChart(div_id = "demo1", grid_left = '1%', direction = 
                   "vertical", data = demo)})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: But download as .csv option not showing there. After saving the default file type, the file is not getting saved in csv type.

Comment: I Changed in UI code and while performing the "reset plot", it takes me to the first tab of tabpanel instead of resetting the plot. I am going to question again this scenario with title: "reset plot with in tabpanel"